# Is there a way to find a fit for a specific curve on a Contour Plot?

Tags: plotting, fitting

I'm kinda new to *Mathematica*, and it's really giving me a hard time, especially since I'm on a timetable.

I have made a contour and I would like to find a function $u(r)$ for the part that starts from $(0,0)$ and goes to $(1.5 , 5)$ (the one that looks like $ln(x)$ ).

[image]

Any ideas? I have read everything but couldnt apply anything

P.S : Here is the code, i want to plot u(R) for the contour (0.0). c1,b1,a1 are constants, and Bernoulifast/slow are constants as well.

```
Show[ContourPlot[
  Simplify[u^2 + d/(u*R^2)^(c - 1) - a/R + 
       b (2 (1 - R^2)/(1 - R^2 u) + (R^2 - 
              R^2 u)^2/(R^2 (1 - R^2 u)^2)) - (Bernoullifast + 
          Bernoullislow)/2 /. c -> c1[[1]] /. a -> a1[[1]] /. 
    b -> b1[[1]]], {R, 0.0, 5.0}, {u, 0.0, 3.0}, 
  ContourShading -> None, PlotPoints -> 300, Contours -> {0.0}]
 , FrameLabel -> {{HoldForm[u], None}, {HoldForm[R], None}}, 
 LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

where

```
    d = 2.72973    
    a1 = 2.03251
    b1 = 1.79216
    c1 = 1.35974
    Bernoullifast = 4.8311
    Bernoullislow = 4.83111
```

Comment: Please post your mathematica code!

Comment: It is not clear from the description and example image why `Fit`, `FindFit` (or `LinearModelFit` / `NonlinerModelFit`) would not work here.  Please look them up.  If you still can't manage, please explain the difficulty in more detail.

Comment: @Szabolcs Really thank you! Didn't know these orders. Will look them up and if no success occurs I will address again here

Comment: Before you can apply  Szabolcs`s hints you must know the points, which ContourPlot  uses. This could be accomplished if the mathematica code is available!!! Still waiting...

Comment: It is not clear to me if OP wants to fit an arbitrary contour to an implicit equation (i.e. fit $f(x,y; \text{params}) = 0$) or fit a simple function (i.e. $y = f(x; \text{params})$). Based on *"i would like to find a function u(r)"* I assumed the latter.

Comment: @ Szabolcs: I agree upon your assumption. Because OP probably used `ContourPlot` I assumed, that the plotpoints are unknown.

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Really sorry for the delay (Father bashed me). I uploaded the code that produced the picture. It's  f(x,y;params)=0.

Again sorry for the delay!

Comment: @billy No problem. But do notice that you didn't include your definition of `Bernoullifast` and `Bernoullislow`.

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform I know, but both of them are constants. so does it really matter?

Comment: @billy Yes, it matters. What value did you assign to these constants?

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform Added all constants on text :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
d = 2.72973;
a1 = 2.03251;
b1 = 1.79216;
c1 = 1.35974;
Bernoullifast = 4.8311;
Bernoullislow = 4.83111;

expr = Simplify[
   u^2 + d/(u*R^2)^(c - 1) - a/R + 
     b (2 (1 - R^2)/(1 - R^2 u) + (R^2 - 
            R^2 u)^2/(R^2 (1 - R^2 u)^2)) - (Bernoullifast + Bernoullislow)/
      2 /.
    {c -> c1, a -> a1, b -> b1}];

Show[
 cp = ContourPlot[expr, {R, 0, 5}, {u, 0, 3},
   ContourShading -> None,
   PlotPoints -> 300,
   Contours -> {0}],
 FrameLabel -> {R, u},
 LabelStyle -> {GrayLevel[0]}]
```

[image]

Extracting the list of all points from the `Graphics`

```
pts = cp[[1, 1]];
```

Extracting the points that make up the lines

```
lines = pts[[#]] & /@ Cases[cp, Line[p_] :> p, Infinity];

ListLinePlot[lines, PlotLegends -> Automatic]
```

[image]

`Select` out the line segments that make up the desired curve

```
co6 = MaximalBy[lines[[6]], Last]

(* {{0.497492, 0.772791}} *)

co3 = MinimalBy[lines[[3]], Last]

(* {{0.501672, 0.773603}} *)

co4 = MaximalBy[lines[[4]], Last]

(* {{3.00167, 1.28342}} *)

co5 = MinimalBy[Select[lines[[5]], #[[1]] > 2 &], Last]

(* {{3.00167, 1.28524}} *)

curve = SortBy[Flatten[{
     Select[lines[[6]], #[[1]] < co6[[1, 1]] &],
     Select[lines[[3]], #[[1]] > co3[[1, 1]] &],
     Select[lines[[4]], #[[1]] < co4[[1, 1]] &],
     Select[lines[[5]], #[[1]] > co4[[1, 1]] &]}, 1], First];
```

Using `FindFormula` to approximate the curve

```
f[x_] = FindFormula[curve, x,
  PerformanceGoal -> "Speed",
  SpecificityGoal -> "Low",
  RandomSeeding -> 0]

(* 0.0275041 + 3.82215 x - 10.5211 x^2 + 20.2627 x^3 - 24.7809 x^4 + 
 19.4933 x^5 - 10.0798 x^6 + 3.45709 x^7 - 0.778036 x^8 + 0.110349 x^9 - 
 0.00893992 x^10 + 0.000315286 x^11 *)

Show[
 ListLinePlot[curve, PlotStyle -> {{Thick, Blue}}],
 Plot[f[x], {x, 0, 5}, PlotStyle -> {{Dashed, Red}}, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Dude, you can't imagine what you save me from... Don't know if I can do anything more than upvote

Comment: RandomSeeding  does not appear to be valid on my notebook tho :( (Still works withouth it somehow :)  )

Comment: Hmm I'm getting some errors... e.g., `co6 = MaximalBy[lines[[6]], Last]` complains that `Part 6 of {...} does not exist.` Is it just me? Any idea what might be going on? Also, my plot is very similar to yours but not identical: https://i.imgur.com/wqJUGHi.png What version are you using? Mine is 10.4.1 for Microsoft Windows (64-bit).

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform - the different number of elements in `lines` might have been caused by version differences (I am using v11.3) or changing the number of `PlotPoints` in the `ContourPlot`. I used `300` because the OP did. If the second plot (colored and legended `ListLinePlot`) doesn't show six `lines` and/or they are not segmented the same way as I show, then you will need to adjust the line segment extraction to compose the final `curve`.